# Rails personal class Each routine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm kind of a newbie in some areas of ruby and rails. So I I'm writing a class to read excel depending on the extension and return the row in a each routine. Something like this:

```
class ExcelRead
  (dependencies)

  def initialize(path, sheet_n = 0)
    type = File.extname(path)

    if type == JitExcelRead::XLS
      Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
      book = Spreadsheet.open path
      book_sheet = book.worksheet sheet_n
    elsif type == JitExcelRead::XLSX
      book = Creek::Book.new path
      book_sheet = book.sheets[sheet_n]
    end

    @book = book
    @book_sheet = book_sheet
    @book_rows = book_sheet.rows
    @path = path
    @type = type
  end
end
```

So this means that I call on my application

```
xls = ExcelRead.new(uploaded_file.filename_path)
```

and everything runs smooth. I have the objects I need at my disposal. My problem now is how to iterate through them. I thought that adding a method to may class like this

```
  def each
    binding.pry
  end
```

and calling it normally on my app like so

```
xls.book_rows.each do |row|
end
```

would make me enter that code, but not really...

help?

Answer (score 0):

If you added a `each` method to your `ExcelRead` class, and you create an instance of this class called `xls`, then you have to access it using `xls.each`, not `xls.book_rows.each`.
Using the former, you are calling the `each` method from the `Enumerator`, as `book_rows` is a collection.
I can only guess that you want a custom way to iterate your `book_row`, so i think something like this should be what you are trying to achieve:

```
def iterate
  self.book_rows.each do |br|
    # do stuff
  end
end
```

And you call it like:

```
xls.iterate
```

But this is only a wild guess.